# Persistent index in python string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, indexing

I'm trying to get string.index() to ignore instances of a character that it has already located within a string. Here is my best attempt:

```
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

def save_alphabet(phrase):
    saved_alphabet = ""
    for item in phrase:
        if item in alphabet:
            saved_alphabet = saved_alphabet + str(phrase.index(item))
    return saved_alphabet

print save_alphabet("aAaEaaUA")
```

The output I'd like is "1367" but, as it only finds the first instance of `item` it is outputting "1361".

What's the best way to do this? The returned value should be in string format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase as alphabet
>>> "".join([str(i) for i, c in enumerate("aAaEaaUA") if c in alphabet])
'1367'
```

*regex* solution (do not prefer regex in this case)

```
>>> import re
>>> "".join([str(m.start()) for m in re.finditer(r'[A-Z]', "aAaEaaUA")])
'1367'
```